# TeXLive 2023 Installation problem - LuaTeX

Tags: texlive, installing

I'm trying to install TeXLive 2023 on Windows 11 by clicking on the installation file install-tl-windows.exe, but get the following error messages - the script has trouble installing LuaTex and fails. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

```
Installing to: C:/texlive/2023
Installing [1/6, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: hyphen-base [22k]
Installing [2/6, time/total: 00:02/16:55]: kpathsea [1048k]
Installing [3/6, time/total: 00:10/01:44]: luatex [1916k]
tar: Could not create file texmf-dist/doc/luatex/base/graphics/luaharfbuzz.pdf: Permission denied
TLUtils::untar: C:\Users\tkpme\AppData\Local\Temp\nsy6FF6.tmp\install-tl-20230911\tlpkg\installer\tar.exe xmf C:\Users\tkpme\AppData\Local\Temp\oDaO3OiY7H\AUtk2muDWv/luatex.doc.tar failed (in C:/texlive/2023)
TLPDB::_install_data: untar failed for https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/luatex.doc.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install luatex
                           luatex will be retried later.
Installing [4/6, time/total: 00:19/03:18]: texlive-scripts [531k]
Installing [5/6, time/total: 00:26/03:01]: texlive.infra [547k]
tar: Could not create file tlpkg/gpg/pubring.gpg: Permission denied
TLUtils::untar: C:\Users\tkpme\AppData\Local\Temp\nsy6FF6.tmp\install-tl-20230911\tlpkg\installer\tar.exe xmf C:\Users\tkpme\AppData\Local\Temp\oDaO3OiY7H\3pld5QX8HI/texlive.infra.tar failed (in C:/texlive/2023)
TLPDB::_install_data: untar failed for https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/texlive.infra.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install texlive.infra
                           texlive.infra will be retried later.
Installing [6/6, time/total: 00:30/03:28]: tlperl.windows [7087k]
Retrying to install: luatex [1916k]
tar: Could not create file texmf-dist/doc/luatex/base/graphics/luaharfbuzz.pdf: Permission denied
TLUtils::untar: C:\Users\tkpme\AppData\Local\Temp\nsy6FF6.tmp\install-tl-20230911\tlpkg\installer\tar.exe xmf C:\Users\tkpme\AppData\Local\Temp\oDaO3OiY7H\Zrrg2N0ByZ/luatex.doc.tar failed (in C:/texlive/2023)
TLPDB::_install_data: untar failed for https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/luatex.doc.tar.xz
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
C:/Users/tkpme/AppData/Local/Temp/nsy6FF6.tmp/install-tl-20230911/install-tl: Writing log in current directory: C:/Users/tkpme/AppData/Local/Temp/nsy6FF6.tmp/install-tl.log
```

Comment: looks as if something is preventing to write a pdf. Typically this happens to me (at updates) because the pdf is open in acrobat, if you are doing a new installation it perhaps means that some defender or virus protection software interferes.

Comment: Sometimes its a pdf that cannot be written, other times a png file, and at yet other times, a directory cannot be written. None of the files are open in Acrobat. I got the installation started by creating the directories that the installer could not create for luatex , and it then went much further, though it reports a png / pdf failure every few minutes. This remains true even after I turn off  my anti-virus and firewall. So while you are likely right to point out that antivirus may be part of the story, it appears not to be the whole story. Is there anything else I should be looking out for?